# Заполнение выпуклой области в $\mathbb{R}^3$ случайными выпуклыми множествами

Tags: python, c++, алгоритм

Я хочу написать алгоритм, который хотя бы в $\mathbb{R}^3$ считает эмпирическую функцию распределения, по созданной случайной модели заполнения выпуклой области в $\mathbb{R}^3$ какими-то объектами (например выпуклыми многогранниками) и по ней оценить функцию распределения, посчитать матожидание и дисперсию. Бросаем в область $\Omega \ \cup_{\forall i} K_i$, Omega - большая область, K_i - бросаемые множества. Случайная величина - количество таких множеств. Любое следующее случайное размещение множества не зависит от предыдущих. Но я не знаю как подступится, не могли бы вы подсказать какие-нибудь решения, которые частично выполняют поставленную задачу, статьи, помочь советом или еще что-нибудь, что может оказаться полезным?

Comment: Ничего не понимаю. Приведите пример.

Comment: Ну например у нас есть область - прямоугольник, мы случайным образом бросаем в нее прямоугольник, затем бросаем прямоугольник в область внутри большого прямоугольника, где нет первого прямоугольника и так до того момента, пока не сможем бросить прямоугольник описанным образом. Для удобства пусть все бросаемые прямоугольники одинаковые. Но мне также интересно, когда мы бросаем произвольное выпуклое множество, не фиксированное

Comment: Как определяется случайная величина?

Comment: Количество таких множеств, которые поместились

Comment: "произвольное выпуклое можество" означает что у вас есть множество таких множеств и вероятностная мера на нём. У вас они есть?

Comment: Если есть, то вы просто бросаете "произвольное выпуклое можество" внутрь вашей области и проверяете пересечение с уже брошенными ранее. Если есть пересечение, останавливаете счёт. Я правильно понял?

Comment: Я задаю все эти вопросы потому что пока не нащупал задачу. В зависимости от "деталей", которые опущены, это может быть тривиальное моделирование а может быть неразрешимая проблема.

Comment: "выпуклой односвязной области" звучит странно. Не бывает выпуклых неодносвязных областей.

Comment: В любом случае, дополните свой вопрос так, чтобы мои вопросы к нему стали бесполезны. Ваш вопрос должен быть самодостаточен без уточнений в комментариях. Спасибо!

Comment: Бросаем в область Omega \ \cup_{\forall i} K_i, Omega - большая область, K_i - маленькие множества. Да, согласен по всей видимости "выпуклой односвязной области" неудачная формулировка